# How to find when a row is inserted or updated in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, row

I have a table in SQL Server but there is no column to show when the value is inserted into the table. And also I don't want to create a one.

Is there a way that I can find the time and date when some one has inserted a row into a SQL Server 2008 table or when it is updated?

Comment: No, there is no way to achieve this - if you need that date/time information, you need to add a column to hold that information, and update it in triggers when inserts and/or updates happen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to modify your existing tables, the only way to go is to create another table to log the activities to. Then you can use `ON INSERT` / `ON UPDATE` triggers on the source tables and log the time and date of inserts and updates to the log table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use On Insert and On Update Triggers in sql server 2005/2008 and your required fields are available in `inserted` and `updated` tables, but if you need to use this information later need to add a new table and log your information on to that!

I myself for doing such stuff like this always add 2 column to my tables

> LastActivityBy relation to user table

and

> LastActivityOn datetime

so you don't need to use any other table.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to alter your existing schema, create a audit table and create trigger on source table to update audit table.